# AWS ElasticBeanstalk sample deployment error 500

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm brand new newbie to AWS and RoR. And I really have no idea where to dig. I'm trying to follow this tutorial:
http://ruby.awsblog.com/post/Tx2AK2MFX0QHRIO/Deploying-Ruby-Applications-to-AWS-Elastic-Beanstalk-with-Git and succeed at first part (until red AWS page with Congratulations).

But when I upload `fooapp` with `git aws.push` and navigate to http://fooapp-env-ftcbuwt5df.elasticbeanstalk.com/ I see "We're sorry, but something went wrong (500)".

It's just default setup, what's wrong can be there? Amazon is a huge pain.

PS. I've tried already to set `consider_all_requests_local = true` and `log_level = :debug`. And error message still has no any details...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this error in my log file:

```
Did not recognize your adapter specification (cannot load such file -- json/ext/parser)
```

Googling on it gave me this article where guy had exact the same issue:

http://www.frontcoded.com/rails-4-amazon-elastic-beanstalk.html

Now everything works as expected.